# Sum over parametric function

Tags: python, function, numpy, matplotlib

I am dealing with a parametric function like this:

[image: Parametric function]

and Ideally I would like to sum over the repeated x axis, as shown in the example. It is to say, for x~4.75, I see that the function can be 0.04, 0.06 or 0.16, and I would like to add a point to the sum of 0.06+0.04+0.16 = 0.26. I need to do that for every point, so that I can construct a function which is a kind of 'projection' of the parametric one. Anyone has an idea on how can I do that in Python?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# set x, y
x = np.arange(-3.,3.,.1)
N = x.size
x[10:13] = x[10]
y = x ** 3 + np.random.rand(N)

# plot curve
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(x,y,'b-')
curve = ax.lines[0]

# get data of plotted curve
xvalues = curve.get_xdata()
yvalues = curve.get_ydata()

# get y for given x 
indexes = np. where(xvalues == x[10]) 
# test print
print xvalues[indexes] 
print yvalues[indexes]
print "Sum of y(x) = ",np.sum(yvalues[indexes]) , " where x = ", x[10]

# define markers
xm = []
ym = []

for x1 in x:
    indexes = np.where(xvalues == x1) 
    print x1, yvalues[indexes]
    if len(yvalues[indexes]) > 1:
        xm += [xvalues[indexes],]
        ym += [np.sum(yvalues[indexes]),]

plt.plot(xm, ym, linestyle = 'None', marker='o', color='g')

plt.show()
```

Test output:

```
x: [-2. -2. -2.]
y: [-7.0936372  -7.42647923 -7.56571131]
Sum of y(x) =  -22.0858277351  where x =  -2.0
```

[image]